# React: Convert HOC const to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, react-google-maps

I am using [React Google Maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps) to add Google Maps to my page, and I am setting up the map here:

```js
import React from "react";
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";

export const MapWithMarkers = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={17}
    center={{ lat: parseFloat(props.lat), lng: parseFloat(props.long) }}
  >
    {props.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.todoId}
          position={{ lat: parseFloat(marker.lat), lng: parseFloat(marker.long) }}
        />
    ))}
  </GoogleMap>
))
```

However, I would like to inject a store and use `this.props.store.lat` rather than `props.lat`, using `@inject('store')`, which requires MapWithMarkers to be turned into a class instead of the const.

I have tried the following:

```js
import React from "react";
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";

@inject('store') @observer
export class MapWithMarkers extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderMarkers = (props) => {
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={17}
      center={{ lat: parseFloat(this.props.store.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.store.long) }}
    >
      {this.props.store.todos.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.todoId}
          position={{ lat: parseFloat(marker.lat), lng: parseFloat(marker.long) }}
        />
      ))}
    </GoogleMap>
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    return withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(this.renderMarkers()));
  }

}
```

This is not working, returning:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: MapWithMarkers.render(): A
>   valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned
>   undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this: `render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const MapUI = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(this.renderMarkers(props)));
    return <MapUI />
}`

Comment: This is returning: 

```Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `loadingElement` is marked as required in `withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(undefined))`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(undefined)) (at Map.js:33)```

```Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `googleMapURL` is marked as required in `withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(undefined))`, but its value is `undefined`.```

```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Required props loadingElement or googleMapURL is missing. You need to provide both of them.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withScriptjs` & `withGoogleMap` are HOC, you should pass a HOC a component. So your component should look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";

@inject('store') @observer
export class Map extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    return <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={17}
      center={{ lat: parseFloat(this.props.store.lat), lng: parseFloat(this.props.store.long) }}
    >
      {this.props.store.todos.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.todoId}
          position={{ lat: parseFloat(marker.lat), lng: parseFloat(marker.long) }}
        />
      ))}
    </GoogleMap>
  }

}

export const MapWithMarkers = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map))
```

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested, but I'm getting the same error :-/

Comment: It's working! Thanks so much, spent a whole day trying to figure this out :D